# UILabel shrink when text changes

Tags: ios6, rotation, uilabel, autolayout

I have a view containing a containerView (gray), which contains a UILabel (blue).

[image]

I have layout constraints such that the containerView is always 8 pixels larger than the label on each side, and the containerView's borders left/top/right are fixed. The container view stretches appropriately when the device orientation changes.

The label's numberOfLines property is set to 0. I am setting the label's text in code. The label's height grows to accommodate the text, as expected.

Here's the problem: When I rotate the device to landscape, the label's width grows to fit into the screen's available width, and the text will fit on 2 lines. But the UILabel does not shrink its height to fit snugly around the text. Notice the extra space above and below the text in the label.

[image]

So how can I make the label's height shrink with the device is rotated to fit snugly around the text?

I have tried calling `[myLabel sizeToFit]` in the `viewWill/DidLayoutSubviews` method, but this had no visible effect.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the label has a constraint that specifies a fixed height:  `NSLog(@"%@", label.constraints);`

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Subclass UILabel.

Step 2: Set the label's custom class to your label subclass.

Step 3: Override `-layoutSubviews` in your custom class.

Step 4: In the overridden method, call `[self sizeToFit];`

This worked for me.